# what does ^A stand for in vim

Tags: vim

I need to replace ^A, ^B in a file, the following command is useless
:s/^A/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the `^A` character, press [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/usr_24.html#24.8) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

If you have configured the "paste" action with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (generally on Windows) you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> instead of it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the ^ with a \, i.e. `s/\^A/^B/`. ^ denotes "start of line" in a regular expression. In the replacement text, escaping is not necessary, but possible.